# Scrollbars not appearing in new window

Tags: javascript, firefox

I'm trying to open a new window, and for some reason the scrollbars will not appear in Firefox or IE, but do work fine in Chrome & Opera.

here's the javascript code on the button (from a PHP script),
and below, if it's more readable, the HTML that is output:

```
window.open('".BASE_URL."utils/viewProfile.php?key=".$key."',null,'width=1280,height=1024,toolbar=0,location=0,directories=0,status=0,menubar=0,scrollbar=1,resizable=1')"

<input class="input-button btn_generic_nav6up" type="button" onclick="window.open('https://domain.com/utils/viewProfile.php?key=8UjKKydCyTx1V7E2A0xklA%3D%3D',null,'width=1280,height=1024,toolbar=0,location=0,directories=0,status=0,menubar=0,scrollbar=1,resizable=1')" value="view profile" />
```

Comment: it works in IE but does not work in IE?

Comment: oops. that was a typo. Thanks for pointing it out, I've corrected it now.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Off the top of my head, I think it's `scrollbars` (plural) and not `scrollbar`.

Also I thought it was `scrollbars=yes` rather than `scrollbars=1`, but it's possible either will work.

Comment: Yep, 'scrollbars=1' is fine, sorry.

Comment: your right. it was a typo. It should be 'scrollbars' not 'scrollbar'

Answer (score 3):

in the window, add this to the stylesheet:

```
html, body{
  overflow: scroll;
}
```

Comment: this doesn't quite work properly. there's a scrollbar, but it's disabled, and it stretches farther than the browser window, so it still can't be used.